# Date/Time selection in bootstrap-datetimepicker is cut off

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, bootstrap-datetimepicker

```
Rails 3.2
```

I am using bootstrap-datetimepicker.js

I have the defaults set to:

```
$.fn.datetimepicker.defaults = {
  maskInput: false,
  pickDate: true,
  pickTime: true,
  pick12HourFormat: false,
  pickSeconds: true,
  startDate: new Date(),
  endDate: Infinity,
  orientation: "auto",
  collapse: true
};
```

But when I try to pick date/time, if the form is at the bottom of the screen, it's cut off.

[image]

I set the orientation to "auto", and I understand that this is supposed to fix the problem, but it's not. Any suggestions?